# Amazon EKS: Moving pods from one node group to another

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I currently have a Managed Node Group serving my EKS cluster and have added another:

- NodeGroup1 [current - 20gb ec2 disk]
- NodeGroup2 [new - 80gb ec2 disk]

I'd like to migrate my current pods from Node Group 1 to Node Group 2 to allow more disk size for the worker nodes, and then stop using Node Group 1.
[image: node groups image]

I've made the new node group as such:

```
eksctl create nodegroup --cluster prod --name NodeGroup2 --node-type t3.medium --nodes 2 --nodes-min 0 --nodes-max 4 --enable-ssm --managed --node-volume-size 80
```

I have a pod disruption budget set up but at the moment I can tolerate downtime. As long as everything makes it over from one managed node group to the new one, I'm happy.

**Can I simply do `eksctl delete nodegroup NodeGroup1` and it will move everything to the second node group?**

Here's what my node groups, deployments and pods look like:

```
~$ eksctl get nodegroups --cluster prod -o json
[
    {
        "StackName": "",
        "Cluster": "prod",
        "Name": "NodeGroup2",
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
        "MaxSize": 4,
        "MinSize": 0,
        "DesiredCapacity": 2,
        "InstanceType": "t3.medium",
        "ImageID": "AL2_x86_64",
        "CreationTime": "2021-11-07T04:15:49.595Z",
        "NodeInstanceRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/eks-node-group",
        "AutoScalingGroupName": "eks-...1d",
        "Version": "1.20"
    },
    {
        "StackName": "",
        "Cluster": "prod",
        "Name": "NodeGroup1",
        "Status": "ACTIVE",
        "MaxSize": 4,
        "MinSize": 0,
        "DesiredCapacity": 2,
        "InstanceType": "t3.medium",
        "ImageID": "AL2_x86_64",
        "CreationTime": "2021-05-25T06:52:25.437Z",
        "NodeInstanceRoleARN": "arn:aws:iam::redacted:role/eks-node-group",
        "AutoScalingGroupName": "eks-...01",
        "Version": "1.20"
    }
    
~$ kubectl get pods -A    

NAMESPACE              NAME                                            READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default                grafana-agent                                   1/1     Running   0          2d23h
default                promtail-2a23                                   1/1     Running   0          3d
default                promtail-2vg2                                   1/1     Running   0          3d
default                prod-application-34                             1/1     Running   0          3d
default                prod-applicationworker-6l                       1/1     Running   0          3d
kube-system            aws-load-balancer-controller                    1/1     Running   0          2d23h
kube-system            aws-node-5rzk3                                  1/1     Running   0          3d
kube-system            aws-node-keljg                                  1/1     Running   0          3d
kube-system            cluster-autoscaler                              1/1     Running   0          2d23h
kube-system            coredns-3254s                                   1/1     Running   0          3d
kube-system            coredns-48grd                                   1/1     Running   0          2d23h
kube-system            kube-proxy-6vx89                                1/1     Running   0          3d
kube-system            kube-proxy-rqb23                                1/1     Running   0          3d
kube-system            metrics-server                                  1/1     Running   0          2d23h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper                       1/1     Running   0          2d23h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard                            1/1     Running   0          2d23h

~$ kubectl get deployments -A
NAMESPACE              NAME                           READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default                grafana-agent                  1/1     1            1           5d23h
default                prod-application               1/1     1            1           160d
default                prod-applicationworker         1/1     1            1           37d
kube-system            aws-load-balancer-controller   1/1     1            1           166d
kube-system            cluster-autoscaler             1/1     1            1           166d
kube-system            coredns                        2/2     2            2           167d
kube-system            metrics-server                 1/1     1            1           166d
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper      1/1     1            1           165d
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard           1/1     1            1           165d
```

If there's a way I can temporarily cordon a whole node group and then drain it, to the other nodegroup (before I delete the first) that would be amazing.

Sorry if this is a simple question but I've ended up reading so many documents that slightly contradict each other.

Cheers, Mike.

Comment: Based on some research, eks managed node groups has [taints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/node-taints-managed-node-groups.html), so setting taint on `NodeGroup1` with `noExecute` should move all pods to another node group. More details about [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/).